# Convert MUSIC algorithm to EV

Tags: power-spectral-density, scipy, music, svd

I write some code, but result looks very strange:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as LA

def music(X):
  # create a signal
  N = 64 
  m = np.arange(N)
  P = 4
  x = np.zeros((N, P+1), dtype='complex')

  x[:,0] = 1.0*np.exp(1j*3.0*2.0*np.pi*m/N)
  x[:,1] = 0.8*np.exp(1j*5.0*2.0*np.pi*m/N)
  x[:,2] = 0.3*np.exp(1j*8.0*2.0*np.pi*m/N)
  x[:,3] = 0.5*np.exp(1j*12.0*2.0*np.pi*m/N)
  x[:,4] = 1.5 * np.random.normal(0, 1, size=N)

  X = np.sum(x, axis=1)

  # MUSIC

  XT = np.mat(LA.toeplitz(X))
  Rxx = XT*XT.H

  en, ev = LA.eig(Rxx)
  _, S, _ = LA.svd(Rxx)

  idx = en.argsort()[::-1]
  en = en[idx]

  EV = np.mat(ev[:,P:]).T
  EVSignal = np.mat(ev[:,:P])

  ref = np.zeros(N, dtype=complex)

  f = np.arange(0, 32, 0.5)

  Mmusic = np.zeros(f.size)
  Ev_psd_alg = np.zeros(f.size)

  for i in range(f.size):
    ref = np.exp(1j*2.0*np.pi*m*f[i]/N)
    REF = np.mat(ref)
    Mult=REF*EV.H*EV*REF.H
    Mmusic[i]=np.absolute(1/Mult)

    Ev_psd_alg[i] = np.absolute(1/( Mult / 1/(S[i]) )) # EV I'm do not sure about it

    Ev_psd_alg[i] = np.abs(1/Mult / S[i])

    Mmusic = 10*np.log10(Mmusic/np.max(Mmusic))
    Ev_psd_alg = 10*np.log10(Ev_psd_alg/np.max(Ev_psd_alg))

  return Mmusic, Ev_psd_alg
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explicitly explain the part you found strange and your corresponding comments so that we can help you better :)

Comment: @OkanErturk EV spectrum looks like MUSIC rotated spectrum. I have tried music and ev methods from spectrum python library and with them no was such problem.

Comment: Can you link to the EV method?

Comment: @Royi https://pyspectrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/spectrum/eigenfre.html?highlight=music#

        if method == 'music':
            PSD = PSD + abs(Z)**2.
        elif method == 'ev' :
            PSD = PSD + abs(Z)**2. / S[I]


I'm  doubt that's code correct

Comment: So are you after reproducing the results of that package in your code?